# Operator overload + (Plus) without changing first term

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, this-pointer

Currently, the code uses a member function operator + overload like this

```
Matrix operator + (const Matrix& B){
    int l = (int)B.a.size();
    int b = (int)B.a[0].size();
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++){
            this->a[i][j] = this->a[i][j] + B.a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
    }
```

Calling the + operator overload looks like

```
Matrix x;
Matrix y;
Matrix result;
result = x + y;
```

The code alters x also because we use this->a[i][j] = this->a[i][j] + b.a[i][j]
the x gets updated to become result.
How do I keep x constant and add the sum of x,y and put it into result?

Comment: How bout... not altering the content of `this`? You can typically just implement `+` with `+=`.

Comment: `auto tmp = *this;`, use `tmp` in for-loop, then return `tmp`;

Comment: (1)  Make the member `const`  i.e.  `Matrix operator + (const Matrix& B) const`.   This will *prevent* changing `x` in the expression `x+y`.  It will also cause assignment to `this->a[i][j]` within the operator implementation to be a diagnosable error (unless `a` is marked `mutable` which it normally shouldn't be).   (2)  In the implementation of the `operator+()`, create another object of type `Matrix`, such as `Matrix result`, assign to elements of `result`, and return `result` rather than `*this`.

Comment: Perferrably implement this at namespace scope. This would allow you to use a argument implicitly convertible to a matrix as first parameter too(but you may want to add overloads where one of the parameters is an rvalue reference reuse memory, if possible...